# It AWS has a native way to explore DocumentDb, without using AWS Internet Gateway to external client?

Tags: aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I create a AWS DocumentDb, and I want to explore it (find or even add items).

But the only way I found how to do it, is to open the VPC to the internet (using AWS Internet gateway) and use Compass or other Mongo client.

Is there is a way that AWS can do it using any other native client within the VPC?

I can't use Internet gateway expose this DB to the internet. (IT Constraints)

Thanks!

Comment: can't you simple launch an EC2 instance in the same VPC, connect to it via session manager / fleet manager (so leaving them in a private subnet) and explore the DB from there?

Comment: I can do it, but a want any GUI client (find queries etc.), and if I understand your suggestions, its all cli, ssh style. Am I right?

Comment: if you launch a Windows instance you can access it via Fleet Manager, which is a Remote Desktop (so, a GUI) in-browser, and it doesn't need any public exposure of the machine. Let me know if it fits your scenario, and I'll post an answer with the details.

Comment: WOW my friend! 
It Works! 
(Even without public VPC), Need to open RDP in security group, and it works!!

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Need also to configure the Fleet - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/setup-instance-permissions.html

Comment: good to know! :) I've posted a more detailed answer below, can you upvote and accept it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario, you can:

1. Launch a Windows EC2 instance in the same VPC
2. Place it in a private subnet
3. [Configure SSM and relative permissions on it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/setup-instance-permissions.html)
4. Connect it via [Fleet Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/it_it/systems-manager/latest/userguide/fleet.html)
5. Install any GUI you need on it